# Inner HTML and event listeners not working together

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a minigame where a user guesses a letter to fill out a random word.

I have an event listener (can be found at the end of `game.js`) that handles when the user types in a letter. What is *supposed* to happen is that the letter the user types gets cleared from the input field, saved to an array, and displayed in `used-letters-display` as green (if it is in the word) or red (if the letter is not in the word), and the letter that is typed should not be able to be used again.

Note: Just to make sure everyone sees, the event listener that handles what happens after hitting enter on the input field is at the very bottom of `game.js`. I was trying to cut down the code to make it easier to see the problem, but it stopped working when I tried, so I have to use the full code.

Clarifying edit, **problem**: When the user types a letter into the letter guess input, the event listener runs and the letter cannot be used again and it will give an alert. However, nothing goes to `used-letters-display` (as in, nothing shows up after the innerHTML) and the letter is not cleared from the input (if I type "d", it should disappear from the input field and be stored to the `usedLetters` array and not be able to be read again). If I comment out the `span` and the `usedLetterTemporary`, this act of the letter disappearing from the input happens. But it stops happening if I uncomment it.

Guys, I'm sorry, but I cannot get rid of anything else, it's a linear game, I do not know what else I can get rid of without ruining the code and making this whole question pointless.

`game.js`:

```
const difficultyArticle = document.querySelector('#difficulty-article');
const difficultyOptions = document.querySelector('#difficulty-options');
const startGameButton = document.querySelector('#start-game');

const playArticle = document.querySelector('#play-article');
const livesDisplay = document.querySelector('#lives-display');
const letterGuessInput = document.querySelector('#letter-guess-input');
const usedLettersDisplay = document.querySelector('#used-letter-display');

const resultArticle = document.querySelector('#result-article');
const displayResults = document.querySelector('#display-results');

let randomWord;
let lives = 0;
let difficulty;
let category;
let correctGuesses = 0;
let incorrectGuesses = 0;
let usedLetters = [];

function playGame(maxTime) {
    let wordInfo = determineWord();
    let randomWord = wordInfo.word;
    let category = wordInfo.category;

    categoryDisplay.innerHTML = `Category: ${category}`;
    livesDisplay.innerHTML = `Lives Left: ${lives}`;
}

function determineWord() {
    let categories = Object.keys(PlayingArrays);
    category = categories.at(Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length));
    let words = PlayingArrays[category];
    randomWord = words.at(Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length));

    return {
        word: randomWord,
        category: category
    }
}

function validateInput() {
    letterGuessInput.value = letterGuessInput.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, '');
}

function endGame() {
    playArticle.classList.add("hidden");
    resultArticle.classList.remove("hidden");

    let div = document.createElement("div");

    div.setAttribute("id", "display-output");
    div.style.width = '100vw';
    div.style.height = '75vh';
    div.style.textAlign = "center";
    div.style.alignItems = "center";
    div.style.fontFamily = "Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif";
    div.style.fontSize = "24pt";
    div.style.fontWeight = "500";
    div.style.border = "0";
    resultArticle.appendChild(div);   
    
    const displayOutput = document.querySelector('#display-output');

    if (lives <= 0 || currentTime == 0) {
        displayOutput.innerHTML = 
        `
            <p>
                Category: ${category} <br>
                The Word To Guess: ${randomWord} <br>
                Time Left: ${currentMinutes}:${currentSeconds} <br>
                Lives Left: ${lives} <br>
                Correct Guesses: ${correctGuesses} <br>
                Incorrect Guesses: ${incorrectGuesses}
            </p>    
        `
    } 
}

playArticle.classList.add("hidden");
resultArticle.classList.add("hidden");

startGameButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let difficulty = difficultyOptions.value;

    if (difficulty == "Easy") {
        maxTime = 300;
        lives = 8;
    }

    if (difficulty == "Medium") {
        maxTime = 225;
        lives = 5;
    }

    if (difficulty == "Hard") {
        maxTime = 150;
        lives = 3;
    }

    if (difficulty == "Impossible") {
        maxTime = 75;
        lives = 1;
    }
    
    difficultyArticle.classList.add("hidden");
    viewResultsButton.hidden = true;
    playArticle.classList.remove("hidden");
    playGame(maxTime);
})

letterGuessInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && letterGuessInput.value != "") {
        let letterGuess = letterGuessInput.value;
        let span = document.createElement("span");

        span.setAttribute("id", `letter${usedLetters[usedLetters.length - 1]}`);
        let usedLetterTemporary = document.getElementById(`letter${usedLetters[usedLetters.length - 1]}`);
        usedLettersDisplay.appendChild(span);
        

        if (usedLetters.includes(letterGuess)) {
            alert("You have used this letter before, try a new one.");
            return;
        }

        usedLetters.push(letterGuess);
        
        if (randomWord.includes(letterGuess)) {
            correctGuesses++;
            usedLetterTemporary.style.color = "green";
        } else {
            livesDisplay.innerHTML = `Lives: ${lives}-1`;
            lives--;
            incorrectGuesses++;
            usedLetterTemporary.style.color = "red";

            setTimeout(() => {
                livesDisplay.innerHTML = `Lives: ${lives}`;
            }, 2500)

            if (lives == 1) {
                livesDisplay.style.color = "red";
            }
        }

        usedLetterTemporary.innerHTML += `${letterGuess}, `

        if (lives == 0) {
            viewResultsButton.hidden = false;
            letterGuessInput.disabled = true;
            clearInterval(countDownInterval);
        }

        letterGuessInput.value = "";
    }
})

viewResultsButton.addEventListener('click', endGame)
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="not giving you that">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Guess That Word</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <article id="difficulty-article">
            <div id="difficulty-display">
                <select required id="difficulty-options">
                    <option value="">---Select Your Difficulty---</option>
                    <option value="Easy">Easy</option>
                    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                    <option value="Hard">Hard</option>
                    <option value="Impossible">Impossible</option>
                </select> <br>

                <button id="start-game">Start Game</button>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="play-article">
                <span id="lives-display"></span>
            </div>

            <button id="view-results">View Results</button>

            <div id="used-letter-display"></div>

            <div id="letter-guesser">
                <input id="letter-guess-input" type="text" maxlength="1" title="Letters Only" placeholder="Your Letter Guess" oninput="validateInput()" required>
            </div>
        </article>

        <article id="result-article">
            <div id="display-results"></div>
        </article>

        <script src="game.js"></script>
        <script src="Arrays.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

`styles.css`:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#difficulty-article.hidden, #play-article.hidden, #result-article.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#title-display {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: baseline;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
}

#title-display h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
}

#title-display h2 {
    font-weight: 800;
    color: red;
}

#difficulty-display h2, #difficulty-display h1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 42.5vw;
}

#difficulty-display p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8pt;
}

#difficulty-display select, #difficulty-display button {
    position: relative;
    left: 42.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 15vw;
    height: 5vh;
}

#play-article {
    font-size: 18pt;
}

#top-screen-display {
    text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
    width: 10vw;
    height: 5vh;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#game-over-message {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#letter-guesser {
    text-align: center;
    height: 10vh;
    position: relative;
    top: 55vh;
}

#letter-guess-input {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 10vh;
    font-size: 18pt;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
}

#view-results {
    position: relative;
    left: 44vw;
    height: 5vh;
    width: 10vw;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

#display-output p {
    font-size: 16pt;
}
```

`Arrays.js`:

```
const Animals = [
    "Aardvark",
    "Albatross",
    "Alligator",
    "Ant",
    "Bug",
    "Butterfly",
    "Buzzard",
    "Carp",
    "Cat",
    "Cockroach",
    "Cod",
    "Coelacanth",
    "Cuttlefish",
    "Dung Beetle",
    "Earwig",
    "Echidna",
    "Falcon",
    "Fiddler Crab",
    "Firefly",
    "Flatworm",
    "Flying Squirrel",
    "Gazelle",
    "Mayfly",
    "Midge",
    "Wallaby",
    "Walrus",
    "Warthog",
    "Wasp",
    "Water Buffalo",
    "Weasel",
    "Weevil",
    "Whale",
    "Whippet",
    "Whitefish",
    "Wild Boar",
    "Wildebeest",
    "Wolf",
    "Wolverine",
    "Wombat",
    "Woodpecker",
    "Wrasse",
    "Yak",
    "Yapok",
    "Yardang",
    "Yellow-Eyed Penguin",
    "Yellowjacket",
    "Yelling Cat",
    "Yerevan",
    "Yeti Crab",
    "Yew",
    "Ylva",
    "Yo-Yo",
    "Yodeler",
    "Yoshi",
    "Yowie",
    "Yoyo",
    "Yurt",
    "Zander",
    "Zebra",
    "Zebu",
    "Zedonk",
    "Zebra Shark",
    "Zebra Turkeyfish",
    "Zorse"
]

const People = [
    { firstName: "Christian", lastName: "Davis" },
    { firstName: "Ada", lastName: "Lovelace" },
    { firstName: "Abraham", lastName: "Lincoln" },
    { firstName: "Albert", lastName: "Einstein" },
    { firstName: "Alice", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
    { firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith" },
    { firstName: "Cleopatra", lastName: "Jones" },
    { firstName: "Charles", lastName: "Darwin" },
    { firstName: "Charlie", lastName: "Davis" },
    { firstName: "Coco", lastName: "Chanel" },
    { firstName: "David", lastName: "Bowie" },
    { firstName: "Emily", lastName: "Brown" },
    { firstName: "Emmeline", lastName: "Pankhurst" },
    { firstName: "Frank", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { firstName: "Frida", lastName: "Kahlo" },
    { firstName: "Galileo", lastName: "Galilei" },
    { firstName: "Grace", lastName: "Taylor" },
    { firstName: "Grace", lastName: "Hopper" },
    { firstName: "Henry", lastName: "Clark" },
    { firstName: "Helen", lastName: "Keller" },
    { firstName: "Ivy", lastName: "Robinson" },
    { firstName: "Isaac", lastName: "Newton" },
    { firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Anderson" },
    { firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Austen" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
    { firstName: "John", lastName: "Kennedy" },
    { firstName: "Katherine", lastName: "Miller" },
    { firstName: "Kylie", lastName: "Johnson" },
    { firstName: "Leonardo", lastName: "da Vinci" },
    { firstName: "Louis", lastName: "Turner" },
    { firstName: "Mia", lastName: "Hill" },
    { firstName: "Marie", lastName: "Curie" },
    { firstName: "Martin", lastName: "King Jr." }
]

const Buildings = [
    "Angkor Wat",
    "Big Ben",
    "Brandenburg Gate",
    "Burj Khalifa",
    "Christ the Redeemer",
    "Colosseum",
    "Eiffel Tower",
    "Forbidden City",
    "Great Wall of China",
    "Hagia Sophia",
    "Louvre Museum",
    "Machu Picchu",
    "Neuschwanstein Castle",
    "Petra",
    "Pyramids of Giza",
    "Sagrada Familia",
    "Sydney Opera House",
    "Taj Mahal",
    "The White House",
    "Taipei 101",
    "The Shard",
    "Tower Bridge",
    "Uffizi Gallery",
    "Willis Tower",
    "Windsor Castle",
    "Yellow Crane Tower"
]

const Climates = [
    "Alpine",
    "Arid",
    "Boreal Forest",
    "Chaparral",
    "Cold Highland",
    "Cold Monsoon",
    "Cold Oceanic",
    "Cold Wetland",
    "Cold Oceanic",
    "Cold Ice Cap",
    "Dry Steppe",
    "Dry Swamp",
    "Dry Tundra",
    "Polar",
    "Polar Alpine",
    "Polar Desert",
    "Polar Ice Cap",
    "Polar Maritime",
    "Polar Tundra",
    "Polar Wetland",
    "Polar Oceanic",
    "Prairie",
    "Subtropical Steppe",
    "Subtropical Wetland",
    "Swamp",
    "Xiaosaurus",
    "Xoloitzcuintli",
    "X-Ray Crab",
    "X-Ray Fish",
    "X-Ray Shrimp",
    "Yellow-Eyed Penguin",
    "Yellowjacket",
    "Yelling Cat",
    "Yerevan",
    "Yeti Crab",
    "Zebra",
    "Zebra Shark",
    "Zebra Turkeyfish",
    "Zedonk"
]

const Countries = [
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "American Samoa",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Anguilla",
    "Antarctica",
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Armenia",
    "Aruba",
    "Australia",
    "Austria",
    "Azerbaijan",
    "Bahamas",
    "Bahrain",
    "Bangladesh",
    "Barbados",
    "Belarus",
    "Belgium",
    "Indonesia",
    "Islamic Republic of Iran",
    "Iraq",
    "Ireland",
    "Isle of Man",
    "Israel",
    "Italy",
    "Jamaica",
    "Japan",
    "Jersey",
    "Jordan",
    "Kazakhstan",
    "Kenya",
    "Kiribati",
    "Democratic People's Republic of Korea",
    "Republic of Korea",
    "Kuwait",
    "Romania",
    "United States",
    "Uruguay",
    "Uzbekistan",
    "Vanuatu",
    "Western Sahara",
    "Yemen",
    "Zambia",
    "Zimbabwe",
    "Åland Islands"
]

const States = [
    "Alabama",
    "Alaska",
    "Arizona",
    "Arkansas",
    "California",
    "Colorado",
    "Connecticut",
    "Delaware",
    "Florida",
    "Georgia",
    "Hawaii",
    "Idaho",
    "Illinois",
    "Indiana",
    "Iowa",
    "Kansas",
    "Kentucky",
    "Louisiana",
    "Maine",
    "Maryland",
    "Massachusetts",
    "Michigan",
    "Minnesota",
    "Mississippi",
    "Missouri",
    "Montana",
    "Nebraska",
    "Nevada",
    "New Hampshire",
    "New Jersey",
    "New Mexico",
    "New York",
    "North Carolina",
    "North Dakota",
    "Ohio",
    "Oklahoma",
    "Oregon",
    "Pennsylvania",
    "Rhode Island",
    "South Carolina",
    "South Dakota",
    "Tennessee",
    "Texas",
    "Utah",
    "Vermont",
    "Virginia",
    "Washington",
    "West Virginia",
    "Wisconsin",
    "Wyoming"
]

const Capitals = [
    "Montgomery",
    "Juneau",
    "Phoenix",
    "Little Rock",
    "Sacramento",
    "Denver",
    "Hartford",
    "Dover",      
    "Cairo",       
    "Moscow",      
    "Seoul",       
    "Oslo",        
    "Wellington",  
    "Beijing",     
    "Rome"
]

const Foods = [
    "Almond",
    "Apple",
    "Apple Pie",
    "Asparagus",
    "Banana",
    "Barley",
    "Beef",
    "Broccoli",
    "Brownie",
    "Kamut",
    "Kettle Corn",
    "Lamb",
    "Lemon",
    "Lemon Bars",
    "Lettuce",
    "Macarons",
    "Mango",
    "Milk",
    "Mousse",
    "Mushroom",
    "Mussels",
    "Napa Cabbage",
    "Natto",
    "Nondairy Yogurt",
    "Nougat",
    "Watermelon",
    "Wonton",
    "Yogurt"
]

const PlayingArrays = {
    Animals, 
    People,
    Buildings,
    Climates,
    Countries,
    States,
    Capitals,
    Foods
}
```

Comment: As others said, please provide an example with no misspelled element IDs or typos. For example, you've just changed `usedLettersAlert` to `usedLettersDisplay` but the former is still used elsewhere in your code. Once you've fixed those bugs, please let us know what the problem is (i.e. ask a question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the `letterGuessInput` event listener and got it working. I added some comments to explain the changes I made.

```js
letterGuessInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && letterGuessInput.value != "") {

        //if the game has not started yet, catch and return to avoid errors.
        //I just used the currentTime variable for this, but you could just as easily set a running variable
        //to true in playGame() and false in endGame() to achieve the same result if you need to change the way
        //the time works.
        if(currentTime<=0){return}

        console.log(letterGuessInput.value);

        let letterGuess = letterGuessInput.value;
        let span = document.createElement("span");

        span.setAttribute("id", `letter${usedLetters[usedLetters.length - 1]}`);
        usedLettersDisplay.appendChild(span);
        //Just move usedLetterTemporary after the element has been appended so it does not throw an error
        let usedLetterTemporary = document.getElementById(`letter${usedLetters[usedLetters.length - 1]}`);
        

        if (usedLetters.includes(letterGuess)) {
            alert("You have used this letter before, try a new one.");
            return;
        }

        usedLetters.push(letterGuess);
        
        if (randomWord.includes(letterGuess)) {
            correctGuesses++;
            usedLetterTemporary.style.color = "green";
        } else {
            livesDisplay.innerHTML = `Lives: ${lives}-1`;
            lives--;
            incorrectGuesses++;
            usedLetterTemporary.style.color = "red";

            setTimeout(() => {
                livesDisplay.innerHTML = `Lives: ${lives}`;
            }, 2500)

            if (lives == 1) {
                livesDisplay.style.color = "red";
            }
        }

        usedLetterTemporary.innerHTML += `${letterGuess}, `

        if (lives == 0) {
            viewResultsButton.hidden = false;
            startTimeButton.disabled = true;
            resetGameButton.disabled = true;
            stopTimeButton.disabled = true;
            letterGuessInput.disabled = true;
            clearInterval(countDownInterval);
            gameOverMessage.hidden = false;
        }

        letterGuessInput.value = "";
    }
});
```

I hope this helps!
to clarify exactly what the issue was, you were trying to reference an element that did not exist yet, so I just moved the target selector after appending the element.
I would also recommend moving `letterGuessInput.value = "";` to the line above where you check if a letter has been used already, right here:

```js
letterGuessInput.value = ""; //move it here

 if (usedLetters.includes(letterGuess)) {
            alert("You have used this letter before, try a new one.");
            return;
        }
```

This simply clears the input regardless of whether the input was right or wrong. This step is not necessary for the game to function, but it does make the experience a bit better.